# Https: Authorization 401

Tags: java, json, rest, api

I'm attempting to establish a connection to an API, which is secured with headers and a token. I have set up a code, which I my self can't see no faults in, and now I've hit a wall. What I wan't to do, is to fetch some JSON data from an URL, but I receive this message:

"Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ..."

The code i'm showing has been tested on fetching JSON from an insecure API, and it worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jsonText = "";

        try {                

                String token = "ttn-account-v2.---";

                URL url = new URL("https://---");

                HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                http.setRequestMethod("GET");
                http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                //http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                System.out.println("token: " + token);

                http.setUseCaches( true );
                http.setDoInput( true );
                http.setDoOutput( true );

                http.connect();

                InputStream im = http.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(im));
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo));

                //Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(im);
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    System.out.println("line: " + line);
                    jsonText = sb.toString();

                    //System.out.println("json: " + jsonText);

                    bw.write(line);
                    bw.newLine();
                    line = br.readLine();

          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

The code should print the JSON data, but instead I receive the http response 401.

Stack Trace:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://---
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)

Comment: Is GET the HTTP method you should use on that site ? Maybe POST would work ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Axel. When I change to POST I receive this message: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/---/api/v2/devices"

Comment: Is the api you are trying to connect using the "basic authentication" scheme to allow users to log in? If so, just giving your token doesn't work, you need to base 64 encode it in a specific way (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: No, they don't provide credentials username:password, but only the base64 token. Should i maybe decode it?

Comment: Speculating about foreign API is nearly useless if not from a forensic perspective. Ask the provider of the API about their required authentication format.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a long shot, but replace

```
http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer" + token);
```

with

```
http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

And mind the space between "Bearer" and the token.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just tried both the space and capital, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. Updated the code in the question :-)